# Prove that $x^2 -2x\sin(x) - 2\cos(x) +2 \leq x^4$ (with Taylor series?)

Tags: inequality, taylor-expansion

I am trying hard to show the following inequality: $$ x^2 -2x\sin(x) - 2\cos(x) +2 \leq x^4, $$ where x is any real number.  The original problem is this: $$ |e^{isx} - 1 - isx| \leq \mathcal{O}(s^2x^2), $$ (at least according to the book where it is written. The inequality should also fit according to WolframAlpha). The lower inequality has already been "simplified" into the one above (although I'm not 100% sure if this is the right approach). I think it should fit better with that, since the absolute value is already gone and therefore the derivatives are more pleasant. I have tried it there also already with the Taylor series, the beginning is also promising, since this begins with $\frac{s^4x^4}{4}$. However, the integral remainder is apparently too imprecise. According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=s%5E4x%5E4%2F4+-2+s%5E5+%28s+x+cos%28s+x%29+%2B+4+sin%28s+x%29%29*x%5E5%2F5%21+%3C%3D+s%5E4x%5E4) the inequality is then no longer correct. I'm a little short of ideas on how else to prove this. Can someone give me a hint? From the feeling, the inequality is also already relatively sharp, so you can't simplify or omit too much more.

Comment: Also try $|\sin(x)|,|\cos(x)|\le1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the  [Taylor remainder formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Estimates_for_the_remainder) in order to solve your original problem. The expansion has the form

$$e^{isx} = 1 + isx + \frac{1}{2}(isx)^2+...,$$

so the remainder-term for the approximation $1+isx$ is $$R_2(x) = \frac{(isx)^2}{2!}e^{is\xi}$$ for some $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$.

Thus, by the remainder formula, we have $$|e^{isx}-(1+isx)| \leq |R_2(x)| = \frac{|isx|^2}{2}|e^{is\xi}| = \frac{1}{2}(sx)^2,$$
since $|e^{i\phi}| =1$ for all $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I didn't even think about it. I always wanted to express the whole expression through the Taylor series. Thank you so much for that! This has already taken me quite a bit of time.

Comment: @Nils Glad I could help ^^